# GoJS how to display different picture inside palette?

Tags: javascript, gojs

excuse me, i want to make a planogram and i want to display different picture inside pallete based on myDiagram.model. but i'm still get the same picture

[image]

i'm following [here](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/planogram.html) for my planogram. If any one have an idea to help I really appreciate it because I need it so much, and thanks to all. sorry for my bad grammar.

Answer (score 0):

data bind `source` on the Picture to something in your Model data.

Something like:

```
$(go.Picture, { margin: 3 },
  new go.Binding("source", "src", function(s) { return "images/" + s + ".png"; })),
```

Which is what [kitten monitor](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/kittenMonitor.html) uses.